# Can you get a shiny and/or female Torchic from Mystery Gift?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I received a male normal Torchic from the Mystery Gift. Can I soft reset to try for a female and/or shiny or will it be counted as received and thus lost?

Comment: Possibly (but I don't think so), since you'll get different IV stats and nature when you get it. It will always be male however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always receive a level 10 Male Torchic with the Speed Boost ability. The nature can be changed, but you will **never** get a shiny or a female. The event runs until January 15.

Source [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/events/2013.shtml)

You can **only** get a shiny through events if that event is for a shiny, otherwise you will get what is described every time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any official conformation, but other sites agree that the Torchic will be a non-shiny male and that you can save before collecting it from the delivery girl to soft reset for different nature/IV. You can also wipe your save and get the Torchic Mystery Gift again provided the event is still running.